# Why does the TypeError occur?

Tags: typeerror

with open(r"C:\Users\GioGio\Desktop\score1.txt", 'r') as f:
a = []
for line in f:
a.append(line.strip('\n').split('\n'))
print(a)
for x in a:
y = ' '.join(x)
z = y.split(' ')
keys = {'学号', '平时成绩', '期末成绩'}
m = dict(zip(keys, z))
score = 0.4 * int(m['平时成绩']) + 0.6 * int(m['期末成绩'])
with open(r"score2.txt", 'w') as p:
p.write(f"{m['学号']}: {score}\n")
b = len(a)

with open(r"score2.txt", 'r') as p:
A = p.readline()
n1 = n2 = n3 = n4 = n5 = 0
for A in A:
if int(A["学号"]) >= 90:
n1 += 1
elif int(A["学号"]) >= 80:
n2 += 1
elif int(A["学号"]) >= 70:
n3 += 1
elif int(A["学号"]) >= 60:
n4 += 1
else:
n5 += 1
c = sum(int(A["学号"]) for A in A)

I've converted the string in A to an integer, why is it still wrong